# ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm interested in this Google Cloud Platform's solution, but I am facing a problem.
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/processing-user-generated-content-using-video-intelligence

I tried to make a issue on this Github repo, but there was no issue tab. So, I post my problem here.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-intelligentcontent-nodejs

I did everything on GCP's Cloud Shell.

I followed the tutorial https://cloud.google.com/solutions/processing-user-generated-content-using-video-intelligence and everything was perfect until I deployed the GCStoPubsub function.

> Deploy the GCStoPubsub function

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/processing-user-generated-content-using-video-intelligence#deploy_the_gcstopubsub_function

First, I tried this.

```
gcloud functions deploy GCStoPubsub --stage-bucket gs://staging-kazu --trigger-topic upload_notification --entry-point GCStoPubsub
```

Then, I got this error message.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) Missing required argument [runtime]: Flag `--runtime` is requir
ed for new functions.
```

So, I added `--runtime nodejs10` and tried again.

```
gcloud functions deploy GCStoPubsub --stage-bucket gs://staging-kazu --trigger-topic upload_notification --entry-point GCStoPubsub --runtime nodejs10
```

Then, I got this bigger error message.

```
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: ...ence/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.3.0-1030-gcp
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/video-intelligence/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=s
tatic_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/video-intelligence/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.20.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
In file included from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack.c:19:0:
../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack.h:38:10: fatal error: grpc/grpc.h: No such file or directory
 #include <grpc/grpc.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:191:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.3.0-1030-gcp
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/workspace/node_modules/@goo
gle-cloud/video-intelligence/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/v
ideo-intelligence/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc"
gyp ERR! cwd /workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/video-intelligence/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.20.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN The package ava is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package sinon is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.7.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.7.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-08-03T08_15_41_930Z-debug.log; Error ID: 49341d49
```

Could you give me any advice, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be hard. I am not able to follow whole procedure, but I hope it will help.

Clould function is running `npm install` during deploy. So I have replicated this error with this command locally (GCP cloud shell precisely) after cloning the github repo. According to my understanding this is related with dependency `"@google-cloud/video-intelligence": "^0.3.0"`.

When I looked at [video-intelligence API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/quickstart-client-libraries) and tried to install it with npm without version it was added to the project with version `"^3.0.1"`. I am not sure if github contains typo or what, however when I correct this dependency to:

```
"@google-cloud/video-intelligence": "^3.0.1"
```

`npm install` command is run without any issues.

This should help with this particular error, however I have no idea what it will be effect on whole process. Anyway I hope it will help! Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is perfect. You are my hero!